# The polynomial $1 + x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$ cannot be written as a sum of $n$ rational squares of polynomials.

Tags: sums-of-squares, real-algebraic-geometry

Artin (1927) settled Hilbert's 17th problem– any nonnegative polynomial can be written as a sum of squares of rational polynomials. Cassels (1964) proved that a if a polynomial admits an SOS decomposition with $n$ rational polynomials, then it admits one with $n$ polynomials.

That is, Cassels shows that for a field $k,$ if one has  $f \in k[x_1,\dots, x_n],$ and $f = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{g_i}{h_i}\right)^2,$ with $g_i, h_i \in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ then $f = \sum_{i=1}^n G_i^2,$ for some $G_i \in k[x_1,\dots, x_n].$ He uses this to prove that $1 + x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$ is not a sum of $n$ squares of rational polynomials. I understand Cassel's proof, though for some reason I feel like it's overkill for this example. Hence my question concerns whether one can simplify the proof that $1+x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$ cannot be written as a sum of $n$ squares of rational polynomials for the special case where $k=\mathbb{R}.$

To make this even simpler, let's restrict to $\mathbb{R}[x],$ and think about why it's impossible to have $1+x^2 = \frac{g^2(x)}{h^2(x)}$ with $g,h \in \mathbb{R}[x].$ Here's my proposed approach: suppose we make the substitution $x = y/z,$ and then multiply throughout by $z^{\deg(h)}$ to homogenize. Then writing (noting that we must have $\deg(g) = \deg(h)-1$)
$$
\overline{h}(y,z) := z^{\deg(h)}h(y/z), \qquad \overline{g}(y,z) := z^{\deg(h)-1}g(y/z),
$$
we have
$$
(\overline{h}(y,z)y)^2 + (\overline{h}(y,z)z)^2 = \overline{g}(y,z)^2. 
$$
I feel like there should be a simple reason why this is impossible, but after scouring the internet and staring at the equation for a long time, I can't see why. Any thoughts on where to draw a contradiction on the above would be much appreciated. Two things I've tried are writing the above expression as:
$$
(\overline{h}(y,z)y)^2 = (\overline{g}(y,z) - \overline{h}(y,z)z)(\overline{g}(y,z) + \overline{h}(y,z)z)\tag{2}
$$
or as
$$
 2yz\overline{h}(y,z) = \overline{g}(y,z)^2 - (\overline{h}(y,z)(y+z))^2,\tag{3}
$$
but then I am not sure how to proceed!

Comment: The proof that $1+x^2$ is not a square in $\Bbb R(x)$ is the same as the proof that $2$ is not a square in $\Bbb Q$. Simply use the fact that $\Bbb R[x]$ is an UFD.

Comment: True, but (correct me if I'm wrong) that doesn't do us any good to explain why $1+x_1^2 + x_2^2$ is not a sum of two rational squares of polynomials. I'm hoping for a reason that generalizes.

Comment: A simple observation is that the RHS can have $yz$ while the LHS cannot have that term.  I’m not sure how to use this, however.

Comment: @MichaelBurr to which equation are you referring? I've given them numbers to make things easier. Thanks for the observation!